# X-editable Edit Values Not Showing Jquery Set Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

I am using X-editable to edit a form with contents that I have. What I am doing is setting the initial values from the database to the html and then allowing the user to press an edit button to edit the values. What is happening is all the values are showing as "Empty" when they click on the edit link for the item, even though the link text is something else.

Example:
Js load: Set value for Firstname to Bob
User clients Edit button which calls .editable('toggleDisabled');
The link now says "Empty" and is empty when edited even though it was set to Bob
Edit textbox shows up but the value is "Empty"

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the value like so:

```
$('.myeditable').editable('setValue', value);
```

You can find this buried in the [X-editable docs](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#editable).